# Xamarin : Reuse an Effect

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have the following

**PlatformEffect** Android Project

```
public class LabelShadowEffect : PlatformEffect
{
   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
      ...
   }

   protected override void OnDetached()
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

**RoutingEffect** .NetStandard Lib

```
public class ShadowEffect : RoutingEffect
{
   ...
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<controls:FontAwesomeLabel

  ...

  <controls:FontAwesomeLabel.Effects>
     <effects:ShadowEffect
        DistanceX="2"
        DistanceY="2"
        Radius="2"
        Color="{StaticResource HeaderTextShadowColor}" />
  </controls:FontAwesomeLabel.Effects>
</controls:FontAwesomeLabel>
```

This works fine, though it would be nice to be able to reuse this as a static resource. So, i notice a can set the property `Element.Effects`, its defined as follows

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Xamarin.Forms.Effect> Effects { get; }
```

I would have thought i could just write a xaml List or an array and put it in a resource and reuse it

**i.e**

```
Effects="{StaticResource StandardShadowEffect}"
```

---

**Attempt 1**, rightclick and create the type, it produces an `system:ArraySegment`

```
<system:ArraySegment x:Key="StandardShadowEffect" x:TypeArguments="Effect">

</system:ArraySegment>
```

> System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a
>   type incompatible with the array

---

**Attempt 2**, List

```
 <generic:List x:Key="StandardShadowEffect" x:TypeArguments="Effect">

 </generic:List>
```

> System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a
>   type incompatible with the array

---

**Attempt 3** : Array

```
<x:Array x:Key="StandardShadowEffect" x:TypeArguments="Effect">

</x:Array>
```

Compile error

> Expected Type IList

---

**Attempt 4** : Just specifying it and using it

```
<effects:ShadowEffect x:Key="StandardShadowEffect"
       DistanceX="2"
       DistanceY="2"
       Radius="2"
       Color="{StaticResource HeaderTextShadowColor}" />
```

Strangely enough this last attempt compiles and doesn't throw, yet no effect is applied

---

Is there anyway to reuse an affect like this, without specifying it on every control? I'm starting to think effects "need" need to be implicitly specified per control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/creating#consuming-the-effect) clearly states that:

> An effect instance can only be attached to a single control.
> Therefore, an effect must be resolved twice to use it on two controls.

So that should expected behaviour. Maybe you can try to extend "needed" UI controls and add a new instance of effect in code behind. Keep in mind that if you do some endless animation in your effect you should remove the effect as well (tricky part).

Comment: I read this page 3 times, and missed the blue note every time

Comment: It is quite hard to pay attention to the blue notes, till you get hit by it multiple times. Currently I scan the blue notes before I read the doc, as they usually contain very important information.